# Implementation of DENSE_RANK

Tags: sql-server, query, rank

I am trying to implement the [DENSE_RANK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dense-rank-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function of SQL Server using only basic SQL functions. I managed to implement the [RANK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rank-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function but I don't know how extend it to DENSE_RANK. More specifically, I don't know how to arbitrarily distinsguish between rows of the same rank.

Here is my implementation of RANK.

```
SELECT A.partition_id,
    A.order_column_id,
    COUNT(B.order_column_id) AS rank
FROM MyTable AS A
INNER JOIN MyTable AS B
    ON A.partition_id = B.partition_b AND A.order_column_id <= B.order_column_id
GROUP BY A.partition_id, A.order_column_id
```

How can I write an implementation of DENSE_RANK in a similar way?

Comment: why do you need to use inner join with table C? it seems you need to use "<" if you don't use descending order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `COUNT(DISTINCT` instead of `COUNT(` - because that’s essentially the difference between `DENSE_RANK` and `RANK`.